# ST TNG "Manhunt" blooper

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

While watching "Manhunt", I notice a scene where Madeline makes an error (in Rex's Bar):

> Jees, Dix. Cuzzo's the guy who iced Marty O'Farron. They never would
>   have nailed him if it hadn't been for you. Your testimony got him
>   ***arranged***.

It was supposed to be "*arraigned*", of course. **But was this a blooper, or was it intentional?**

Comment: It's an intentional joke / verbal pun that Madeline is a bit of a dope and doesn't quite understand things. That sort of thing fits the time / genre depicted - bubble headed secretary, etc...

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site. I'm... not entirely sure what you're trying to ask here. What exactly is your question? Are you just pointing out a blooper? I'm afraid that it's really not clear at all from your question. Would you mind [edit]ing to clarify and highlight what your actual question is? Thanks.

Comment: Is it a blooper, or is it intentional as @NKCampbell suggests?

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me what OP was asking. It's also pretty answerable

Comment: I've twitted at the actress as well as the show's scriptwriter and director. Hopefully we can get a definitive response

Answer (score 4):

### This seems to be a fairly common variant of the "[brainless beauty](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrainlessBeauty)" trope.

We, the audience know that the word is 'arraigned' but by having her mouth it as 'arranged', it conveys to the audience that while Madeline may be loyal, resourceful and clearly besotted with Dixon Hill, she's not the brightest bulb on the porch.

There's another variation of this joke in [TNG: Clues](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/188.txt)

> **MADELINE:** *Doesn't matter if you're from the moon, Hon. Mister Hill is incommuni... incommunica...*
>
> **GUINAN:** *Incommunicado.*
>
> **MADELINE:** *That's it. Sorry, Hon.*

The [original screen direction](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/113.txt) for her in [TNG: The Big Goodbye](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Big_Goodbye_(episode)) was that she was a

> a plain blond with a ***bubbly personality***

which does seems like Hollywood code.

---

On a related note (and apropos of nothing) you may find it interesting that she was entirely absent in the scene [as originally written](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/145.txt). Dix enters the bar and speaks to Rex but Madeline was nowhere to be seen.